# When I start the ADB, system completely freezes

Tags: linux, adb, ubuntu-16.04, freeze

When I start the ADB in command line:

```
$ sudo adb start-server
```

I get message like this:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now in port 5037 *
* daemon started successfuly *
```

And after this system(Ubuntu 16.04(x86_64)) completely freezes.

How I can fix this problem?

**UPD:** I run

```
strace adb start-server
```

and get, which system freezed on command `nanosleep`.

Answer (score 0):

on my system i have solved my problem with plugging in laptop power.
when my laptop is connected to power cord. adb works. and when i is on battery its gonna freeze.
i think this is something with Acpi.

another solution:
to start using adb when i am on battery:
sudo tlp ac
and when i want to quite:
adb kill-server
sudo tlp start

Comment: it worked with disabling tlp: TLP_ENABLE=1
in /etc/default/tlp

Comment: i have make an issue regarding this:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145040485

Answer (score -1):

Try upgrading to 16.10 and make sure you have the following set in your BIOS:
- From Legacy to UEFI boot 
- Disabled USB 3.0 legacy

Ref: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2313496

Answer (score -1):

I choose poprietary driver and this work, but not all time, sometimes this problem repeated.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem on my archlinux system (with ANY version of the kernel).

The problem for me seems to be the usb auto-suspend function of tlp. I've disabled it completely setting:

```
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0
```

And for the moment it seems to have solved the problem.

EDIT: It wasn't the usb autosuspend i had to uninstall completely tlp to make it work until i can investigate this further.

Answer (score -1):

Fo me, it was tlp

Edit the conf file at  /etc/default/tlp

I did

```
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0
```

and

```
USB_BLACKLIST_PHONE=1
```

Maybe you don't need to put USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0

EDIT: doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: It seemed to work. But then it stopped working, so I also uninstalled TLP